Look into specific information in txt file and paste it into Excel
I am working in Excel, to look into a txt file for certain information and then paste it into the worksheet.
I want to copy information from different lines that contain different defined strings.
Example:
txt file is a like a logbook. This logbook has entrances like |UPDATED|, |CREATED| and |UPDATED|. After this is is logged, then a variable number of lines will follow, until the "topic" is closed with the symbol "->".
I want the script to, look for the string |UPDATED|, copy the whole line and paste into Excel. Then keep scrolling through the txt file lines, until "->" is found, copy that line and put it right under the correspondent "title" (UPDATED, CREATED, UPDATED).
If there was a way to also record the line it found the entrance into a variable, then I could do, for example const= const - 2, to go up in txt file for two lines and also copy that content!
Sub PS_automation()

Dim ReadData As String
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer, p As Integer
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
p = 1

Open "C:\Users\racastr1\Desktop\PS_AUTOMATE.txt" For Input As #1 
    
Do Until EOF(1)
    
    Line Input #1, ReadData 
    
    If InStr(Left(ReadData, 9), "|CREATED|") Then
        Cells(x, 1) = ReadData
        x = x + 1
    Else
        If InStr(Left(ReadData, 8), "|CLOSED|") Then
            Cells(y, 2) = ReadData
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If InStr(Left(ReadData, 9), "|UPDATED|") Then
                Cells(z, 3) = ReadData
                z = z + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Loop
Close #1
End Sub

This already copies the mentioned entrances, but if I had the same condition to find "->" it does not paste it into the worksheet in order (so it does not get into the associated "title").
File Example:


I think you will be better off loading the file in question using Power Query and processign it using Power Query.  There is likely no need for any VBA code.

Another way would be to go to open, select the folder where the text file is, then change the file type to text files.   A Text import Wizard will pop-up and you can walk through it.

Appreciate the suggestions so far!
This is something to use on a daily basis, 3 to 4 times a day. That being said, I wanted to automate a macro in excel, so it only demanded to export the txt and then let the macro do the job, reducing time in this task.
Are your suggestions also time-effective?

Note: I will not be the only one using this and needing to perform this task. That being said, a macro would guarantee that the output would be the same across all colleagues

If you add While (InStr(ReadData, "->") = 0): Line Input #1, MoreData: ReadData = ReadData + vbCrLf + MoreData: Wend just after each of the If InStr(Left(ReadData, 9), "|...|") Then then it will contactenate more strings until it sees a ->
`

Thanks @JerryJeremiah! Indeed it did work. But it copied everything form the || up to and including ->. Anyway it can be altered to ignore everything in between and only print || + -> blahblahblah?

@rfccastro You just need to use an if statement in the loop.  Change ReadData = ReadData + vbCrLf + MoreData to if (InStr(ReadData, "->")) ReadData = ReadData + vbCrLf + MoreData

You could try something like this (changed my approach from the initial answer)
Sub PS_automation()
    
    Const TXT_PATH As String = "C:\Users\racastr1\Desktop\PS_AUTOMATE.txt"
    
    Dim data As String, arr, arrCols, i As Long, s As String, col As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, n As Long, v, sPrev As String
    
    data = GetContent(TXT_PATH)        'read the whole file
    data = Replace(data, vbcrlf, vbLf) 'normalize line separators
    arr = Split(data, vbLf)            'split to array
    
    'array of label+colNumber pairs
    arrCols = Array("|CREATED|", 1, "|CLOSED|", 2, "|UPDATED|", 3)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific sheet
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr) 'loop over the lines from the file
        s = arr(i)   
        'Loop over `arrCols` and check for pre-defined label....
        For n = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols) Step 2
            v = arrCols(n)            'label
            If Left(s, Len(v)) = v Then  'match?
                col = arrCols(n + 1)  'corresponding column number
                If i > 0 Then 'go back up and check for date?
                    sPrev = arr(i - 1) 'the line above the match
                    If sPrev Like "####-##-## *" Then 'starts with date?
                        'write line with date to sheet if found
                        ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sPrev
                    End If
                End If
                ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = s
                GoTo skip 'done with this line
            End If
        Next n
        
        If Left(s, 2) = "->" Then
            If col > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = s
            End If
        End If
skip:
    Next i
End Sub


Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 1).ReadAll()
End Function


Really appreciate Tim! It is doing what I wanted to indeed.
I am quite unfamiliar with coding in general. I mainly try to work with what I little know and from what I can understand might be beneficial from other threads.
If you look into the image I show as an example of the txt file, it also has some entry dates. The dates are usually above the ||. I tried to do i = i - 1 (go back 1 line after founding the string), then copy and paste and move to the ||. It does not seem to work though. Any thoughts on this?

If a date is found then where should it be put? FYI If s Like "####-##-## *" would match a date at the beginning of the line, if it's in YYYY-MM-DD format as shown in your sample file.

Hmm, understand!
So, the txt file is polluted with a lot of dates. So my main filter are the entrances described (|*| type), then once it finds one of those, it first go back a specific number of lines, take the info in that line (as it will be the date) and make it the first entrance in the excel. After setting the date entrance, it goes back to where it found the || entry and copy/paste and then move further until it founds -> and copy/paste

See my update above - changed up my approach a bit because the Select Case was a bit clunky.

Seems like that did the trick! Thanks for the support Tim (and all the rest)!
